# PowerBi - How to drag measure to column in matrix chart and create subheader for columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset here

```
Name   Type Result    Start time             End time
Abc     A    Ans     5/5/2023 13:12:33  5/5/2023 13:12:43
Abc     A    Ans     5/5/2023 14:12:33  5/5/2023 14:14:33
Abc     A    Ans     5/5/2023 16:45:33  5/5/2023 16:46:33
Abc     B    No ans  5/5/2023 16:55:10  5/5/2023 16:57:46
Efg     A    No ans  5/5/2023 13:15:44  5/5/2023 13:17:38
Hij     B    No ans  5/5/2023 13:15:44  5/5/2023 13:15:44
Hij     B    No ans  5/5/2023 15:07:56  5/5/2023 15:08:00
hij     A    No ans  5/5/2023 18:21:01  5/5/2023 18:23:55
```

I need to create a matrix chart that looks like this
[image]

Initially I tried it to do with measure, it works but I could not create the subheading like "A", "B", or "Total". I also tried to pull the measure of total time into the column of matrix, but it is not working as well.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this :

| Name | A_Ans | A_No_ans | B_Ans | B_No_ans | Total_Ans | Total_No_ans | Total Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 00:06:56 |
| Efg | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 00:02:12 |
| Hij | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 01:02:10 |